# Google Maps SDK and additional OpenGL Controller on top

Tags: google-maps, opengl-es

I'm trying to use Google's new Maps SDK with added child view controller stacked on top of Google Maps. Google Maps by itself work fine and just as expected. So does my openGL controller (GLKit) when used without maps. 
But while dragging the map GLKView is calling setNeedsDisplay and you can see the map is not being fully drawn. Only when stoped dragging the map the view is fully restored.

I have the project on gitHub: https://github.com/rendulic/GMaps3D

I'm also aware of Googles issue: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4752, but non of the work arounds don't work for me.

I have 2 controllers: 
- ViewController (which inits Google Maps)
- OpenGLController (child controller of ViewController)

ViewController's google maps init in viewDidLoad:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

// setting up mapView
_mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:46.550814 longitude:15.645118 zoom:18 bearing:0 viewingAngle:65];
_mapView.camera = camera;
_mapView.delegate = self;
_mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;
_mapView.settings.compassButton = YES;
_mapView.settings.myLocationButton = YES;

_mapView.settings.zoomGestures = YES;

// defining landscape size and portrait size on the map view
_portraitRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, _mapView.frame.size.width, _mapView.frame.size.height);
// adding status bar height
_landscapeRect = CGRectMake(0, 0,_mapView.frame.size.height + [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height, _mapView.frame.size.width);

// adding button view relative to mapView
MapMenuView *menuView = [[MapMenuView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( _mapView.frame.size.width - 50, 50, 60, 80)];
menuView.tag = 6661; // unique tag for the view (needed after orientation change so the position can be modified)
[self.view addSubview:menuView];


UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
_openGLController = (OpenGLController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"openGLController"];

[_openGLController setPreferredFramesPerSecond:30];

[self addChildViewController:_openGLController];
[self.view addSubview:_openGLController.view];
[self didMoveToParentViewController:self];

// set delegate for openGL redraw
[self setViewControllerDelegate:_openGLController];
```

}

And this is the OpenGL Setup in OpenGLController:

```
 EAGLContext *firstContext = [EAGLContext currentContext];

_glView.context = firstContext;
_glView.delegate = self;

if (!_glView.context) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to create NSContext");
}

_glView.drawableMultisample = GLKViewDrawableMultisample4X;
_glView.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat16;
_glView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

// init effect
_effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];

// init textures
NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                          GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft,
                          nil];

NSError * error;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"barrack" ofType:@"png"];
GLKTextureInfo * info = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:path options:options error:&error];
if (info == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Error loading file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}


_effect.texture2d0.name = info.name;
_effect.texture2d0.enabled = true;


// 60 frames per seconds call
/*CADisplayLink* displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(render:)];
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[displayLink setFrameInterval:1/60];
*/

// prepare buffers
glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Indices), Indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, Position));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0);
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (const GLvoid *) offsetof(Vertex, TexCoord));

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

}

This is what drawInRect is performing:

```
[self setupGL];
[self update];

glClearColor(0,0,0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glFlush();

[_effect prepareToDraw];

glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, [[TextureManager sharedTextureManager] getTexture:TEXTURE_BARRACK]);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(Indices)/sizeof(Indices[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

glFlush();
```

Comment: i've just made it work on simulator but it doesn't work on my iPhone 4S. The version i have pushed onto github